# Increasing performance when comparing two lists

Tags: c#, performance, list

What options do I have when it comes to comparing items in two lists? I'm having some performance issues, and I would like to know if there are any faster alternatives:

```
int[] foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] bar = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 };

var result = foo.Any(x => bar.Contains(x));
```

Regardless if I use the lambda methods or use a `foreach` on my own, I assume that the performance loss will still be `O(N^2)`. Can I do anything to affect that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = foo.Intersect(bar).Any();
```

That creates `Set<T>` from `bar` items and then enumerates `foo` until first match found. Internally that looks like:

```
Set<int> set = new Set<int>();

foreach (int local in bar) // M times
    set.Add(local); // O(1)

foreach (int value in foo) // N times max
{
    if (!set.Remove(value)) // O(1)
        continue;

    yield return value;
}
```

As Patryk Ćwiek correctly pointed, that gives you O(N+M) instead of O(N*M)

Comment: Wouldn't this still create an internal nested loop nontheless?

Comment: `Intersect` is a set operation, which means that the set creation + iteration over one of the collections (assuming the `Contains` operation on set is ~`O(1)`) will yield `O(N+M)` asymptotic complexity, instead of `O(N*M)`, similar to the other answer using `HashSet` explicitly.

Comment: I see. Are there any other lambda methods besides intersect that creates sets when comparing collections?

Comment: @Johan [`Except`, `Union`, `Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546153.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Hashset:

```
int[] foo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] bar = { 6, 7, 8, 9, 1 };
var hashSet = new Hashset<int>(bar);
var result = foo.Any(x => hashSet.Contains(x));
```

Or you can use `Except` with Any like this:

```
var result =  !foo.Except(bar).Any();
```

I bet that is race with the [Sergey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21426069/3010968) :p

Comment: While ideally the comparison on the `HashSet` should be O(1) now, wouldn't this just shift the "performance loss" on creating the `HashSet`?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar maybe but the query will be faster which that is the point I guess.But ofcourse Sergey's [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21426069/3010968) is more elegant

Comment: You mean `var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(bar);` (compile error otherwise)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I noted it [in comments here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21426069/1180426) that creating a set *once* will make this solution `O(N+M)`. If you were recreating the set for each of second collections' elements inside `Any` (and set creation is `O(N)`), that would revert the solution back to `O(N*M)`.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, here's a benchmark program to test the various answers in this thread.

It seems to show that the HashSet approach is marginally fastest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            var foo = Enumerable.Range(     0, 100000).ToArray();
            var bar = Enumerable.Range(100000, 100000).ToArray();

            int trials = 4;

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

            for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
            {
                sw.Restart();
                method1(foo, bar);
                Console.WriteLine("method1()     took " +sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();

                for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
                    method2(foo, bar);

                Console.WriteLine("method2()*100 took " +sw.Elapsed);

                sw.Restart();

                for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j)
                    method3(foo, bar);

                Console.WriteLine("method3()*100 took " +sw.Elapsed);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private static bool method1(int[] foo, int[] bar)
        {
            return foo.Any(bar.Contains);
        }

        private static bool method2(int[] foo, int[] bar)
        {
            var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(bar);
            return foo.Any(hashSet.Contains);
        }

        private static bool method3(int[] foo, int[] bar)
        {
            return foo.Intersect(bar).Any();
        }

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

The results (release build) on my PC are as follows. Note that I ran method2() and method3() 100 times each because they are so much faster than method1():

```
method1()     took 00:00:12.2781951
method2()*100 took 00:00:00.4920760
method3()*100 took 00:00:00.7045298

method1()     took 00:00:11.9267980
method2()*100 took 00:00:00.4688330
method3()*100 took 00:00:00.6886865

method1()     took 00:00:11.8959856
method2()*100 took 00:00:00.4736563
method3()*100 took 00:00:00.6875508

method1()     took 00:00:11.9083229
method2()*100 took 00:00:00.4572404
method3()*100 took 00:00:00.6838919
```

Comment: +1 manual creation of HashSet with looking for Any contained item is a little bit faster

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy But it's so marginal that I personally would stick with your slightly more readable answer.